# To prove $(a ∗ b^{−1} ∗ a)^3 = I$.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $(G, ∗, I)$ is a group and $a, b ∈ G.$ satisfy $a^2=b^3=I$. 
Then I need to prove $(a ∗ b^{−1} ∗ a)^3 = I$.

My Work:-

$(a ∗ b^{−1} ∗ a)^3$

$a ∗ b^{−1} ∗ a * a ∗ b^{−1} ∗ a * a ∗ b^{−1} ∗ a$

$a ∗ b^{−1} ∗ b^{−1} ∗ b^{−1} ∗ a$     $\qquad$  { as $a^2=I$ given }

*but from here onwards I am not getting exact steps to solve it. Does anyone have an idea?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: invert both sides of $b^3=1$.

Comment: what will be the way of doing it. or you mean by using {Leibniz}

Comment: $(b^3)^{-1} = (b^{-1})^3$

Comment: Ok, so then it will become $I^{-1}$, so does $I^{-1}$ and $I$ are one and the same thing. Can we write $I$ in place of $I^{-1}$

Comment: Yes. $I$ is the identity, so it is equal to its own inverse. $I=I^{-1}$

Comment: That's correct. Since $1 \cdot 1 = 1$, $1^{-1} = 1$.